# LUFA with Eclipse but without Makefile

Tags: makefile, usb, cdc

I want to use LUFA for my ATMEGA32U4 to communicate via CDC. So to start I created a project in Eclipse and imported the LUFA folder and the files for the Device VirtualSerial demo. The thing is, that I want to do that without using the makefile (mostly because I have never used makefiles before). Is that possible and what do I need to do? I have tried a lot, but I get errors all the time. Is there any instruction?
Thanks!
Sebastian

P.S.: Just to be clear. I  want to use the "Managed Builder", so that I don´t have to do anything with the makefile, but Eclipse does that for me.

P.P.S.: I also tried http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/files/LUFA/Doc/140928/html/_page__exporting_library.html
with AS7 and Eclipse, but it didn´t work with both.....

P.P.S.: When I try to build the project I get the error

'Building target: Test1.elf'
'Invoking: AVR C Linker'
avr-gcc -Wl,-Map,Test1.map -mmcu=atmega32u4 -o "Test1.elf"  ./LUFA/Platform/UC3/Exception.o ./LUFA/Platform/UC3/InterruptManagement.o  ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/XMEGA/Template/Template_Endpoint_Control_R.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/XMEGA/Template/Template_Endpoint_Control_W.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/XMEGA/Template/Template_Endpoint_RW.o  ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/XMEGA/Device_XMEGA.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/XMEGA/EndpointStream_XMEGA.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/XMEGA/Endpoint_XMEGA.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/XMEGA/Host_XMEGA.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/XMEGA/PipeStream_XMEGA.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/XMEGA/Pipe_XMEGA.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/XMEGA/USBController_XMEGA.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/XMEGA/USBInterrupt_XMEGA.o  ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/UC3/Template/Template_Endpoint_Control_R.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/UC3/Template/Template_Endpoint_Control_W.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/UC3/Template/Template_Endpoint_RW.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/UC3/Template/Template_Pipe_RW.o  ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/UC3/Device_UC3.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/UC3/EndpointStream_UC3.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/UC3/Endpoint_UC3.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/UC3/Host_UC3.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/UC3/PipeStream_UC3.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/UC3/Pipe_UC3.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/UC3/USBController_UC3.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/UC3/USBInterrupt_UC3.o  ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/AVR8/Template/Template_Endpoint_Control_R.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/AVR8/Template/Template_Endpoint_Control_W.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/AVR8/Template/Template_Endpoint_RW.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/AVR8/Template/Template_Pipe_RW.o  ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/AVR8/Device_AVR8.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/AVR8/EndpointStream_AVR8.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/AVR8/Endpoint_AVR8.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/AVR8/Host_AVR8.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/AVR8/PipeStream_AVR8.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/AVR8/Pipe_AVR8.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/AVR8/USBController_AVR8.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/AVR8/USBInterrupt_AVR8.o  ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/ConfigDescriptors.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/DeviceStandardReq.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/Events.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/HostStandardReq.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Core/USBTask.o  ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Host/AndroidAccessoryClassHost.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Host/AudioClassHost.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Host/CDCClassHost.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Host/HIDClassHost.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Host/MIDIClassHost.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Host/MassStorageClassHost.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Host/PrinterClassHost.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Host/RNDISClassHost.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Host/StillImageClassHost.o  ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Device/AudioClassDevice.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Device/CDCClassDevice.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Device/HIDClassDevice.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Device/MIDIClassDevice.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Device/MassStorageClassDevice.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Device/PrinterClassDevice.o ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Device/RNDISClassDevice.o  ./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Common/HIDParser.o  ./LUFA/Drivers/Peripheral/XMEGA/Serial_XMEGA.o ./LUFA/Drivers/Peripheral/XMEGA/TWI_XMEGA.o  ./LUFA/Drivers/Peripheral/AVR8/Serial_AVR8.o ./LUFA/Drivers/Peripheral/AVR8/TWI_AVR8.o  ./LUFA/Drivers/Board/Temperature.o  ./LUFA/Build/DMBS/Template/Template.o  ./LUFA/Build/DMBS/DMBS/HID_EEPROM_Loader/HID_EEPROM_Loader.o  ./Descriptors.o ./VirtualSerial.o
./LUFA/Build/DMBS/DMBS/HID_EEPROM_Loader/HID_EEPROM_Loader.o: In function `main':
HID_EEPROM_Loader.c:(.text.startup.main+0x0): multiple definition of`main'
./LUFA/Build/DMBS/Template/Template.o:Template.c:(.text.startup.main+0x0): first defined here
./VirtualSerial.o: In function `main':
VirtualSerial.c:(.text.startup.main+0x0): multiple definition of`main'
./LUFA/Build/DMBS/Template/Template.o:Template.c:(.text.startup.main+0x0): first defined here
./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Device/AudioClassDevice.o: In function `Audio_Device_ProcessControlRequest':
AudioClassDevice.c:(.text.Audio_Device_ProcessControlRequest+0xf8): undefined reference to`CALLBACK_Audio_Device_GetSetEndpointProperty'
AudioClassDevice.c:(.text.Audio_Device_ProcessControlRequest+0x15a): undefined reference to `CALLBACK_Audio_Device_GetSetEndpointProperty'
AudioClassDevice.c:(.text.Audio_Device_ProcessControlRequest+0x182): undefined reference to`CALLBACK_Audio_Device_GetSetInterfaceProperty'
AudioClassDevice.c:(.text.Audio_Device_ProcessControlRequest+0x1e4): undefined reference to `CALLBACK_Audio_Device_GetSetInterfaceProperty'
AudioClassDevice.c:(.text.Audio_Device_ProcessControlRequest+0x236): undefined reference to`CALLBACK_Audio_Device_GetSetEndpointProperty'
AudioClassDevice.c:(.text.Audio_Device_ProcessControlRequest+0x284): undefined reference to `CALLBACK_Audio_Device_GetSetInterfaceProperty'
./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Device/HIDClassDevice.o: In function`HID_Device_ProcessControlRequest':
HIDClassDevice.c:(.text.HID_Device_ProcessControlRequest+0xd0): undefined reference to `CALLBACK_HID_Device_CreateHIDReport'
HIDClassDevice.c:(.text.HID_Device_ProcessControlRequest+0x18e): undefined reference to`CALLBACK_HID_Device_ProcessHIDReport'
./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Device/HIDClassDevice.o: In function `HID_Device_USBTask':
HIDClassDevice.c:(.text.HID_Device_USBTask+0xa2): undefined reference to`CALLBACK_HID_Device_CreateHIDReport'
./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Device/MassStorageClassDevice.o: In function `MS_Device_USBTask':
MassStorageClassDevice.c:(.text.MS_Device_USBTask+0xf4): undefined reference to`CALLBACK_MS_Device_SCSICommandReceived'
./LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Common/HIDParser.o: In function `USB_ProcessHIDReport':
HIDParser.c:(.text.USB_ProcessHIDReport+0x5bc): undefined reference to`CALLBACK_HIDParser_FilterHIDReportItem'
./LUFA/Build/DMBS/DMBS/HID_EEPROM_Loader/HID_EEPROM_Loader.o: In function `main':
HID_EEPROM_Loader.c:(.text.startup.main+0x4): undefined reference to`_binary_InputEEData_bin_size'
HID_EEPROM_Loader.c:(.text.startup.main+0x6): undefined reference to `_binary_InputEEData_bin_size'
HID_EEPROM_Loader.c:(.text.startup.main+0xe): undefined reference to`_binary_InputEEData_bin_start'
HID_EEPROM_Loader.c:(.text.startup.main+0x10): undefined reference to `_binary_InputEEData_bin_start'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Test1.elf] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!
There were a lot of c-files, that were unnecessary, but eclipse wanted to compile them anyway. I excluded them and now it´s working.